# Change 2x to 2*x with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal with this is to change for example: `2x` to `2*x`. What I tried to do is:

```
string.replace(new RegExp("[0-9]+x", "g"), //what here?);
```

But can't figure out what to replace it with. I need reference to the numbers and the `x` to be able to put `number + "*" + x`. If you know of other solutions without using RegEx, that is fine too.

Comment: You mean `2x2` > `2*x2`?

Comment: If Javascript had supported lookbehind I would had done `(?<=\d)(?=x)` and replaced zero width with `*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI1uZ7/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
string.replace(/(\d+)(x)/g, '$1*$2')
```

First of all, you do not need to use `new RegExp(...)`, just enclose the RegEx in `/`, like `/[0-9].other.data/`. Use a `g` after the ending `/` to make it global like in your example above - `/this.is.a.global.regex/g`

Secondly, `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`

In the second argument, it has `$1` and `$2`. These refer to the `1`st and `2`nd capture groups respectively. `$n` will contain the data from the `nth` capture group

---

Demo:

```js
string = '2x'
new_string = string.replace(/(\d+)(x)/g, '$1*$2')

document.write(new_string)
```

---

Shorter version:

```js
string = '2x'
new_string = string.replace(/\d+(?=x)/, '$&*')

document.write(new_string)
```

---

Comment: You can avoid the second backreference since `x` is a known, literal subpattern. Just use `x` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: @Yoshi: That is a question to everyone here :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know, but I had to choose one, didn't want to spam all the answers ;P

Comment: @Yoshi I did not think you had to escape them, however I saw another answer did just after I posted mine, and so I escaped it too. I though maybe it was safer, though I had never done it before! Changed it back now! `;)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was typing the shorter version with only one backreference as you posted the comment. The first was just so the OP could understand how they work, and so the RegEx was not edited too much.

Comment: The shorter version adds a * to every number even the ones without an x after them.

Comment: *Shorter* with regexes is often not the best thing. See comment above. Shorter patterns are either imprecise, or involve more backtracking than longer, but more efficient patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You need only one number to look and a lookahead with x

```js
document.write('2x'.replace(/\d(?=x)/g, "\$&*"));
```

Comment: `$0` cannot be used in JS, you need `$&`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, in ie11 it works with `$0`, thank you for pointing me to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I can make it:

```
string.replace(/\d(?=x)/g, '$&*')
```

Comment: I did not think of that, it is shorter! +1

Comment: Actually, I made mine shorter! Why use the `(?=x)`, just use `/\d+/` like so, `string.replace(/\d+/, '$&*')`

Comment: @Druzion (?=x) is needed or else it will select more numbers than nessesary.